# how to run "react-native bundle xxx" in build.gradle

Tags: android, react-native

In React Native android, if I want generate a apk, firstly I must to run "react-native bundle xxx" to generate index.android.bundle and copy to "assets", is there a way I can do this in gradle?
I write "react-native bundle xxx" in updatejs.sh, I can run it by "sh updatejs.sh" in terminal and it works fine, but when I call it in gradle like:

```
commandLine 'sh', 'updatejs.sh'
```

it will show error : "updatejs.sh: line 11: react-native: command not found", anyone know how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate `apk`, check in official documentation [Generating Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html).